# Showing view controller from AppDelegate when notification arrived

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard

I am tring to show `UIViewController` which is inside the `UIStoryboard`. There isn't any problem about poping up the view. But the navigation is not working in the popup viewcontroller; such as when I touch back button

```
 [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

I am using that code in `AppDelegate` --> `didReceiveRemoteNotification` method

```
 UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
 PFProfileInfoVC *viewcontroller = [mystoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SBID_ProfileVC"];
 viewcontroller.strAuthorID = [userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"][@"targetId"];
 [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thanks,

Comment: Here by replacing the root view controller you are destroying the whole vc presentation hierarchy. Maybe what you want to do is to add it to the current main Navigation controller.  if the rootViewController of the window is a navigation controller you might be able to push your VC to this navigation controller. `[self.window.rootViewController pushViewController: viewcontroller animated:YES]`

Comment: Thanks. So via presentViewController, do I remove all the created controllers?. Also it should be `[self.window.rootViewController.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];`

Comment: Yes (you remove al created controllers) and Yes (i missed the navigation controller part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `presentViewController`, the viewController is not pushed onto the navigation stack. Normally, it is presented modally. So if you want to dismiss it, use

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your support. Is there any other options to show the existing viewcontroller in storyboard? without creating new one?. Just like jump to spesific viewcontroller in storyboard hierarchy?